# How to use SQL variable in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: mysql, variables, batch-processing, laravel-5.3

I'm trying perform a batch query, example as follows:

```
    foreach ($getRecordsFromAllTempTable as $key => $value) {

$studentId = $value["csv_student_id"];
$csvDescription = $value["csv_desc"];
$csvAmount = $value["csv_amount"];
$transaction_category = $value["csv_cat_id"];
$transaction_type = $value["csv_transaction_type"];
$batch_desc = $value["batch_desc"];

        $batchSqlQuery .= "

            INSERT INTO ". StudentRegisterTransaction::TABLE ." 

            (student_id,transaction_type, transaction_category, description, amount, created_time, created_date, created_by)

            VALUES 

            ($studentId, '". $transaction_type ."',$transaction_category, '". $csvDescription ."', '". $csvAmount ."', 
            '".  $datetime ."', '". $date ."',".session('userid').");

            set @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

            INSERT INTO ". StudentRegisterTransactionUploadLog::TABLE ." (transaction_id, student_id, batch_id, amount, description,  
            payment_category, created_by ,authorized_by, created_time) 

            VALUES 

            (@lastid, $studentId, '". $batchId ."', '". $csvAmount ."', '".$batch_desc."', $transaction_category, ". session('userid') .",
             '". session('email') ."', '". $datetime ."');


             DELETE FROM ". studentregisterTransactionTempLog::TABLE ." WHERE id=" . $value['id'] . ";


            ";
    }

            \DB::insert(\DB::raw($batchSqlQuery));
```

but when I do I'm getting the following error:

```
[2017-01-29 21:35:33] 173.194.83.243.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

It looks like Laravel cannot understand the MYSQL variable or I'm doing something wrong. However if I run the query directly in the database it works fine.

Comment: You're using Laravel. Why would you ever write such low-level SQL code, and more to the point why would you do it **without escaping**? Use prepared statements [as described in the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries).

Comment: Well I wanted to use batch query with large number of insert statement for multiple table.

Comment: You're over-optimizing here, you've made a total mess of the situation. `insert` takes one statement and one statement only. You haven't given a lot of context here but I bet you could do this with `INSERT INTO x SELECT ... FROM y` if you worked at it.

Comment: the problem here is in the ** set @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();** SQL statement, given the SQL; is there any other alternative way would you suggest? basically I wanted to get the inserted ID, if I try to do via application because of large number of query DB communication takes long time.

Comment: This whole thing needs a rethinking. You're not batch inserting here, you're running a gazillion statements all mangled together. If you were actually doing a proper multi-insert I might be more supportive of this approach, but you're not. Look at ways of using the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...` method where you can insert data from one table into another, transforming it as necessary.